# ASP.NET MVC URL Routing with Single Route map

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

i am trying to add a correct route to my Asp.net MVC website.

- **www.example.com/profile/39 ( Profile/{id} )**: its for showing profile of some one.
- **www.example.com/profile/edit ( Profile/edit )**: its for editing current user profile

and here is my routes :

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute("ShowProfile",
          "Profile/{id}",
      new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" });


         routes.MapRoute(
             name:"Profile",
             url: "{controller}/{action}"
             );



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

my problem is when i put `ShowProfile` route first it shows profiles correctly but when i enter `www.example.com/profile/edit` it show an error for missing `Int` value and  when putting `Profile` route first an 404 error is shown for `www.example.com/profile/39`.
i tried to fix this problem with changing my route to :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("EditProfile",
            "Profile/Edit",
            new { controller = "Profile", action = "Edit" });

            routes.MapRoute("ShowProfile",
      "Profile/{id}",
  new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

in this format it works fine for both situation but it shows an 404 error for other posting method like :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult EditEmail()
    {

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");

    }
```

but i don't want to add a route value for all my methods , is there any general way for not adding one by one routing values ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your controllers. Probably they really doesn't contain these actions that returns HTTP404.

This approach works well for me and all URLs works:

- localhost:24934/profile/5
- localhost:24934/profile/edit
- localhost:24934/home
- localhost:24934/home/main
- localhost:24934/home/main/7

Controllers:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Main()
    {
        return View();
    }
}    
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        @ViewBag.id = id;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("EditProfile",
            "Profile/Edit",
            new {controller = "Profile", action = "Edit"});

        routes.MapRoute("ShowProfile",
            "Profile/{id}",
            new {controller = "Profile", action = "Show"});

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",    
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
}
```